# How to disable playlist song hover info in Amarok?

Tags: amarok

Anyone know how to disable this annoying hover info in Amarok 2.4? I browsed through all the options (not that there is much of them), but couldn't find how to turn that feature off... It's getting in the way when hovering over songs with your mouse and really is not necessary.

Thank you.

Comment: I see you added the `thank you` part, which I removed. I'm not going to remove it (it's no big deal), but note that here there's no need for such (we consider it noise, and are only interested in the meat of the question itself), and in fact we consider participating more to be a better way to show gratitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I poked around and couldn't find anything either, so I asked on IRC

> Mamarok: xenoterracide: this is addition tag info, it can't be disbled currently, there already is a bug report for it

So maybe it'll be disable-able in 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

It may be turned off now, at least in 2.4-git. However, make sure that the choice to allow the "tooltips" is unchecked in every playlist layout you use. Playlist > Playlist Layouts.